# CKEditor - Changing style sets on-the-fly with JQuery

Tags: ckeditor

I want to set and re-set the style dropdown in CKEditor on-the-fly with styles pull from a DB. I'm having trouble trying to set it dynamically using JQuery. Here's a dumbed down scenario:

For instance, using CKEditor with an extra dropdown next to it. In the dropdown menu there is a list of style sets: Cool, Warm, Hot

When a user selects a style, I'm pulling the corresponding styles from the DB and creating an array to change the default style dropdown in CKEditor with the styles associated with the set.

Currently the only way I've been able to get it to work is to destroy the instance of CKEditor and re-instantiate a new instance with the styles:

```
 var editor = $('#editor').ckeditorGet(); 
 editor.destroy();

 if(set == "cool"){
  //AJAX Call to get styles from DB.....
  //loop through results and build styleArray

  CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('cold', styleArray);

   $('#editor').ckeditor( function() { /* callback code */ }, 
      { 
    stylesSet: 'cold'
   });

 }
 ...
```

Is there any way to just clear out the current styles in the dropdown and repopulate it without destroying the editor? The UX is jacked up when the UI has to pause and wait for the death and rebirth of the editor.

Comment: To clear out the default styles in the Styles dropdown, you can set this in "config.stylesSet = [];" in config.js